# Bank Balance required for Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, proof-of-funds

My wife and I plan to visit Greece for 7-8 days in month on June. I just wanted to confirm how much bank balance is required in the account for the visa approval. We plan to visit 2 islands (Santorini and Mykonos).

Also before this we applied for US tourist visa in March'16 to visit my sister, but we did not get the visa with the reason stated "No strong ties" however the interviewer did not check any of our papers. I would also like to know that will this have an impact on getting the Schengen visa?

Comment: What do you mean with "did not check any of our papers"? Usually, it's up to you to submit all the necessary documentation.

Comment: It's likely that the interviewer examined your papers at some point before or after your interview.

Comment: @Relaxed I understand it's not uncommon for people to bring additional supporting documents to the interview for a US visa (as [recommended](http://canberra.usembassy.gov/step5_niv_process.html)) and then be frustrated when the officer denies the application without looking at those documents.

Comment: I was going to comment on it in my answer but the prior US visa denial is an entirely separate question. You might want to post it as such but note that having been denied a visa previously (even a Schengen visa, certainly a US visa) is not a reason for a refusal and not a big problem. OTOH, intent to return to/ties with your country of residence is also an important criterion for Schengen visa so if you haven't been able to prove that the US consular officer's satisfaction, you might want to pay special attention to that and join any relevant document you have to the current application.

Comment: Did not check means, it was an interview at the US embassy and he just asked us a couple of questions and did not ask for any supporting documents from US, however we had taken all our documents. and when u apply for a US visa they do not ask for any document submission its just an online form u fill.

Comment: @n8484 I don't have much experience with US consulates but for your next (Schengen) visa application, if you have relevant documents that make you look good, volunteer them, don't wait for anybody to ask for them.

Comment: Also, the fact that your sister lives in the US might be a disadvantage, there is always the suspicion that you might want to go live with her/rely on her support to immigrate illegally. That's much less of a concern when going to an obvious tourism destination where you have no family.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but actually i consulted a travel agency for the package and the agent told me that as per Schengen visa rules if u have US visa rejection u cant apply for Greece visa. So wanted to confirm if we have any such clause.

Comment: That's definitely not the case, such a rule is nowhere to be found in the regulations, the only official automatic reason for a refusal is if a Schengen country has put a ban/warning about you in the Schengen Information System and that does not happen automatically for all immigration violation, let alone for a mere visa refusal so how could it be the case for a refusal *by a third country*?

Comment: At the same time, I certainly don't want to suggest that it does not matter at all. The Greek consulate will be able to see the refusal stamp and might therefore be extra careful when reviewing your application. Schengen countries have a similar (if not identical) set of criteria than the US so having been refused a US visa before is less than ideal. But nothing forbids you to apply and if your application is strong and you make sure to address the objections raised last time (ties to your country of residence), you still have good chances of success.

Comment: Travel agent is lying, Greece is in Schengen, n their form does not ask for any type of visa refusal, deportation, criminal things etc. Also, US Embassy does not stamp any refusal stamp on passport.

Comment: Not official guidelines, but the minimum bank balance could be around 1 Lac Indian Rupees, after allocating the tour expenses. Flight can be from Credit Card, n some consulate does not even ask for fully psid flight. If they ask just in case, KLM offers no questions asked full refund of any type of ticket, if you apply for it before departure and upload the official visa refusal letter. Hotels xan ve found easily on booking.com. Show them your true intentions as tourist, your rough daily plan, why europe/greece/islands, etc

Comment: Thanks everyone for you quick responses, give me hope that i can go ahead and apply for schengen visa. Thanks once again for your views and will reach out if need any more help.

Comment: This is the reply i have got from the travel agent, they are syaing due to US rejection i cant apply schengen visa within 6 months of rejection.
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------On your request I have re – checked with the Visa team for the Applying the Schengen Visa ,they are saying as per the expert advise you cannot apply for the Schengen Visa if you got rejection of the USA visa in month March , now you can only apply after 6 month .
 
 
Rest you choice we will not assist you regarding the visa land package

Comment: It sounds like this is a rule the travel agent has then and they won't assist you with your visa application. You are, of course, free to apply on your own. The Greek officials will also expect you to show strong ties to your country though, so you should do your best to address whatever issues you can from your US visa application.

Comment: I agree with @ZachLipton.  Suppose someone is rejected by the US because their application was poorly prepared (this may in fact be your case).  Waiting six months has no benefit; the only path to success is through submitting a higher quality application.  The same is true of a subsequent application to an entirely different jurisdiction, for example, to Greece.  You should apply directly or, if you find that prospect daunting, find a different and perhaps more reputable service to help prepare the application.

Comment: Also, be careful not to be too focused on bank balance.  If you "park" funds in your bank account in the hope of beefing up your application, you are actually hurting yourself, because it appears that you are trying to misrepresent yourself, and that damages your credibility.  If it looks like you're parking funds for the application, it is likely to be denied for that reason alone.

Answer (score 3):

There is a reference *per diem* amount required to satisfy the "means of subsistence" requirement, which is €50 for Greece. So that works out to about €400 for your trip. But that's a minimum amount, you also have to show that you have a stable situation and that the costs of the trip you're planning is commensurate with your means. That's why it's best if your bank statement shows evidence of a regular income rather than a large amount of cash.

Answer (score 2):

The usual requirement from a Schengen embassy is €35-50 per day. For my fifteen day trip I technically had to give proof for €580. Obviously €580 for a fifteen day trip is way too little; you should know it and definitely the embassy knows it. It would be much easier if each one of you shows a bank statement for thrice their minimum amount. A good amount for a 7-8 day trip would be €1300-€2000 each